# newid() as column default value

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a table with a uniqueidentifier column. 
What is the Default Value or Binding i should set in order for each new row to generate a new uniqueidentifier?

Setting the default to newid() always returns 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

**EDIT**:
Apparently i got it all wrong, the insert was done from Entity Framework, and it doesn't handle this scenario.

[Entity Framework - default values doesn't set in sql server table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652396/entity-framework-default-values-doesnt-set-in-sql-server-table)

Comment: No, setting the column default to NEWID() definitely does work. Post your code so we can tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Consider using NEWSEQUENTIALID() instead of NEWID().  This will generate incremental values which can improve performance if the column is indexed, especially the clustered index.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`newid()` should work.

See images below:

[image]

[image]

You have another issue there.