# EF:6 - How to skip insertion of value if value has default value set in DB?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I'm fighting trough with Entity Framework 6 and MySQl Database

I got everything to work, however I'm confused with dates or not obligatory values.

In my database, in "Users" table I have column "RegistrationDate" which has default value of "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"
what is mean that if value not provided at insertion time it will insert default value = date time of the server

I got my schema reverse engineered into C# and all perfectly works, however when I insert "User" without setting a date to "RegistrationDate" property, it insert into Database new date as "0001-01-01 00:00:00" and ignore "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP".

So im wondering how to set it to ignore "RegistrationDate" and do not insert anything into db if it wasn't specifically set to some date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a guess that the SQL EF generates is setting the field value. Even if you don't set in code, EF doesn't know that the database has a default value, and doesn't know that he should ignore it.

[This article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193958.aspx), from 2011, says that there is a `DatabaseGenerated` attribute, which you could use like this:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGenerationOption.Computed)]
public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }
```

So, EF now knows that it should retrieve the data when you query the database, but should rely on the database to set the value.

However, I don't know what it would do if you explicitly set the value. Maybe it will ignore it, which may be not what you really want.

I didn't test it, it's just a guess, but it's a nice solution in my opinion.

**[Edit1]** Some months ago, I saw [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9Il79a2uBU), and the guy does something like this in his DbContext class (i believe you have it) at 49:12 (the video is in portuguese)(i have modified the code, but didn't test it):

```
//This method will be called for every change you do - performance may be a concern
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    //Every entity that has a particular property
    foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(entry => entry.Entity.GetType().GetProperty("YourDateField") != null))
    {

        if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
        {
            var date = entry.Property("YourDateField");

            //I guess that if it's 0001-01-01 00:00:00, you want it to be DateTime.Now, right?
            //Of course you may want to verify if the value really is a DateTime - but for the sake of brevity, I wont.
            if (date.CurrentValue == default(DateTime))
            {
                date.CurrentValue = DateTime.Now;
            }   
            else //else what? 
            {

                //Well, you don't really want to change this. It's the value you have set. But i'll leave it so you can see that the possibilities are infinite!

            }
        }


        if (entry.State == EntryState.Modified)
        {
            //If it's modified, maybe you want to do the same thing.

            //It's up to you, I would verify if the field has been set (with the default value cheking)
            //and if it hasn't been set, I would add this:

            date.IsModified = false;

            //So EF would ignore it on the update SQL statement.

        }

    }



}
```

Comment: Super! that is exactly what I was asking about! Thank you very much! Just did a test, works like a charmed!

Comment: Thanks, but could you do a little test for me? Try explicitly setting the value, just to see what happens. I guess it will ignore the value you set. Just to see how it behaves - i'm also interested in this thread :D

Comment: Uhhh :( you right, it is now ignoring value completely, even if it was specificity set.

Unfortunately I cant now mark you answer as an answer :(

Comment: No problem. As I can see, this is not a trivial problem. I have seen some solutions in Entity Framework itself, which doesn't rely on the database.

I'll edit my question, but still I think is not what you want. Also, it relies on reflection.

Comment: Edit made! It doesn't rely on the database, but I think you could use the the `IsModified = false` property to achieve the same results, relying on the database when the value is null.

Comment: Thank you for your update, for my simple case overriding entire SaveChenges() method would be an overkill, its easier just to set the value to DateTime.Now and ignore default "current_timestamp" in DB.

Answer (score 1):

I think many of us have been caught out by default database values when dealing with EF - it doesn't take them into account (there are many questions on this - e.g. [Entity Framework - default values doesn't set in sql server table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652396/entity-framework-default-values-doesnt-set-in-sql-server-table) )

I'd say if you haven't explicitly set a datetime and want it to be null, you'll need to do it in code.