# Entity framework (EFv1 .net 3.5) is not saving the data when ms sql table consists default field value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, wcf, .net-3.5

I have a table which looks like:

```
[dbo].[Person](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [SysDate] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Person_SysDate]  DEFAULT (getdate())
```

In my `Wcf service` I'm using `entity framework` but it doesn't work properly i.e. it is not saving the data model when the table has default field value.

**Working solution which is not acceptable:**

```
public void InsertPerson(Person model)
{
   using (DbEntities db = new DbEntities())
   {
      db.AddToPerson(new Person() { Name = model.Name, SysDate = DateTime.Now });
      db.SaveChanges();
   }
}
```

**Non working solution - solution which I'm tring to achieve:**

```
public void InsertPerson(Person model)
{
   using (DbEntities db = new DbEntities())
   {
      db.AddToPerson(model);
      db.SaveChanges();
   }
}
```

Comment: Found a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35093135/2587691

Comment: Good, but EFv1 is pretty bad, compared to any later version.  If you make ongoing changes to this codebase, you should upgrade to .NET 4x and EF 6.1.3.

Answer (score 1):

Would you please include any error information you get from the debugger when it fails in the 'Non working solution - solution which I'm tring to achieve:'

Also please try the following and see if this works.

```
public void InsertPerson(Person model)
{
   using (DbEntities db = new DbEntities())
   {
      db.Entry(model).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;
      db.SaveChanges();
   }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: There is no `db.Entry()` method.

Comment: I am happy to see you found a solution :)